# How to troubleshoot iOS UIWebView DOM Exception 18?

Tags: exception, dom, ios, html, uiwebview

My team of developers has built a successful iOS universal app which synchronizes sophisticated HTML5 web apps to an iPhone / iPad. The apps are loaded into the UIWebView from the local file system. We recently added in-app email using MessageUI.framework.

Everything was going fine until our QA department identified a use case where the instantiation of the MailCompose class causes the UIWebView to throw a SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 error. This ONLY occurs on iOS 4.2.1. The app functions normally when built against SDK 4.1 and installed on a device running iOS 4.1. This FEELS like either an iOS 4.2 bug, or an HTML5 issue that has appeared in iOS 4.2.

I am looking for techniques to find the cause of the SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18. I know that this error is a same-origin exception of some kind, but it doesn't make sense why it works on 4.1 but not 4.2. And why does the MailCompose class cause the issue?

Any help at all will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: r u able to crack this situation?, m facing the same?

Answer (score 2):

may I ask how do you load your html source from the local FS ? 
Also what does your ***MailCompose*** class do, to interact with the document loaded into the UIWebView ?

If you are reading the contents of an html file into a string and then load it into the UIWebView, then you have to change it, and load it using the `file://` protocol.

Instead of loading the html source as a string :

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[path stringByAppendingString:@"path to the html file"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL]; 
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];
```

Go ahead and load the actual html file via an NSURLRequest (file:// url)

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]; 
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[path stringByAppendingString:@"path and file name of the file"]]; 
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:baseURL]; 
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Doing so, enables access to window.localStorage, window.openDatabase and other objects.

Cheers

Comment: In fact, I am loading the HTML with NSURLRequest as you suggest. And we are already making extensive use of window.localStorage and window.openDatabase. I am now able to avoid the DOM exception by completely removing the UIViewController with the UIWebView from memory before displaying the MailCompose action sheet. But I was never able to determine why the DOM exception was occurring. BTW, MailCompose is part of MessageUI.framework & MFMailComposeViewController.

Comment: thanks, loading the page through a NSURLRequest solved it for me